# When is minimal element $=$ least element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Suppose $\langle S,\in\rangle$ is well-ordered and $A\ne \emptyset\subseteq S $

If $x\in A$ is a minimal element of $A$, does that mean it is also the least element of $A$ since $S$ is totally ordered?

Comment: Yes, correct. Minimal and least mean the same in totally ordered sets.

Comment: FYI, use \langle and \rangle for $\langle\rangle$.

Comment: $A\ne\emptyset\subseteq S$ means $A\ne\emptyset$ & $\emptyset\subseteq S$ which is the same as $A\ne\emptyset$ since $\emptyset\subseteq S$ adds nothing. If you want to say that $A$ is a nonempty subset of $S,$ write $\emptyset\ne A\subseteq S,$ or, better yet, write "$A$ is a nonempty subset of $S.$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $(S,\le)$ be an ordered set. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. For all $x,y\in S$, either $x\le y$ or $y\le x$.
> 2. For all $H\subseteq S$, for all $m\in H$, either $m$ is not minimal in $H$ or $m$ is the minimum of $H$.

*Proof:* $[(1)\Rightarrow (2)]$. Let $H\subseteq S$. If $H=\emptyset$, the conclusion is vacuously true. So, let $m\in H$. If $m$ is not minimal, there is nothing to prove. If $m$ is minimal, we want to prove that $\forall h\in H,\ m\le h$. Let $h\in H$; by $(1)$, $h\le m\vee m\le h$. If $m\le h$, there is nothing to prove. If $h\le m$, by minimality $m=h$, and thus $m\le h$, QED.

$[(2)\Rightarrow (1)]$. The conclusion is vacuously true if $S=\emptyset$. So, let $x\in S$ and $y\in S$. Apply $(2)$ to $H=\{x,y\}$. If $x$ is the minimum of $H$, then $x\le y$. If $x$ is not minimal in $H$, then $y\ne x$ and $y\le x$. Either way, at least one between "$x\le y$" and "$y\le x$" holds. QED

> So, "Yes" to the question in the body.